# Trait PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCaseTrait not found?

Tags: php, phpunit, php-7.1

After upgrading to PHP7.1.2 and PHPUnit 6.0.8 (compiled from source and downloaded the phar, respectively), my previous tests which extended PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase no longer work, and it appears ([in the docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html#database.configuration-of-a-phpunit-database-testcase)) that I should be using traits instead.

So, running my test with the class declaration like this:

```
class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
```

Used to work, but, changing to:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCaseTrait;

class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    use TestCaseTrait;
```

Causes the following error:

```
Fatal error: Trait 'PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCaseTrait' not found in /path/to/FooTest.php on line 17
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the fact that DbUnit is no longer bundled in the PHAR distribution of PHPUnit as of version 6 (see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/6.0/ChangeLog-6.0.md#removed).

Have a look at https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit#php-archive-phar for information on how to use DbUnit now.

Comment: that was it. The docs need an update, they still say "the phar contains all the dependencies you need." (and wow! Sebastian Bergmann answered!) I'll open a github ticket for the page that needs an update.

Comment: Well, DbUnit is not a required dependency. So it's not needed.

Comment: if DbUnit is not a required dependency propose alternative: another library, sth else, what? (it is required but is not a dependency)

Comment: TL;DR: There is no (official) replacement. A longer discussion can be found here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit/issues/217

Answer (score 1):

If your are suffering this problem in **PHP5.6** (DbUnit 1.3), please

```
use PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase_Trait;
```

instead of

```
use TestCaseTrait;
```

Comment: This is incorrect (or, at the very least, very outdated). The proper use statement for the current version is `use PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCaseTrait;`. You should probably also read the previous answers. The *author* of PHPUnit and DBUnit already answered this above. See also: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/database.html#configuration-of-a-phpunit-database-testcase

Comment: I know, and I use PHP5.6, and the author's answer didn't solve my problem. It's my fault that I didn't mention PHP's version at the first time. But maybe another person is also maintain an outdated project, and he may also encounter this problem.

Comment: Downvote removed because that's a reasonable. It should be noted, however, at the time of this writing, PHP 5.6 lost active support 1 year 8 months ago, and will lose security updates in 3 months (December 2018). PHPUnit *long* ago lost support for the version mentioned in this comment. Reference: https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php